# UIPageViewController while using UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll doesn't stop at the second index

Tags: ios, iphone, uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

I am working on an app which requires `UIPageViewController` using `UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll`. I had implemented using http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-tutorial-intro/ everything works fine, when i change the view,the content also changes according to the index of the `UIPageViewController`, but the only problem is that it doesn't change the **navigation label** title according to the index of the `UIPageViewController`. Means, for e.g i have total 3 pages, for the first page and the third page it shows the label title properly but as soon as i change the view to second , the content of the second view appears and the label title also appears correct for a few seconds only and after that it takes the label title of the third view. Similarly when i come back from third view to second view the label title takes the title of first view. I am not getting where i am doing mistake. Any suggestions??

Comment: I got my answer using [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17608179/pageviewcontroller-delegate-functions-called-twice)