# Why Code in PageViewController is occurring twice?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm creating `pageViewController` inside `createViewController()` method. I have defined one property of  `UIPageViewController` which is `self.pageController`.
Because of repeating chunk of code, When these pages open then it also showing behind of view when we left scroll page.

```
func createPageController()
    {
        var deviceFrame:CGSize = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size
        self.pageController = UIPageViewController(transitionStyle: UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyle.Scroll,
            navigationOrientation: UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientation.Horizontal,
            options: [UIPageViewControllerOptionInterPageSpacingKey : 0])

            self.pageController!.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,108, deviceFrame.width, deviceFrame.height-110)
            self.dailyChallengeViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main_iPhone", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DailyChallengeViewController") as? DailyChallengeViewController
            self.winnersViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main_iPhone", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("WinnersViewController") as? WinnersViewController

// All the below code will repeat 1 more time
 self.winnersViewController!.view.frame = self.pageController!.view.frame
        self.dailyChallengeViewController!.view.frame = self.pageController!.view.frame

        self.dailyChallengeViewController!.index = 0
        self.winnersViewController!.index = 1

        self.viewControllers = [self.dailyChallengeViewController!,self.winnersViewController!]
        self.pageController!.setViewControllers([self.dailyChallengeViewController!],
            direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward,
            animated:false,
            completion:nil)
        self.addChildViewController(self.pageController!)

        self.view.addSubview(self.pageController!.view)

        self.pageController!.dataSource = self
        self.pageController!.delegate = self

 self.pageController!.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
}

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?{
}

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?{
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As I did understand, many people have this issue.

It's because of the *viewControllerBeforeViewController* and *viewControllerAfterViewController*.

It is recommended to use the *willTransitionToViewControllers* to get the current index of your PVC alongside the other two methods stated above.

In other words, if you want a specific thing to happen at index x, write an if statement in the *willTransitionToViewControllers* delegate method.

Hope this helps you!

[PageViewController delegate functions called twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17608179/pageviewcontroller-delegate-functions-called-twice)