# PageViewController showing the index of the page incorrectly?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller

I have followed this tutorial for creating PageViewController http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-storyboard-tutorial/
What the problem is iam getting of the page incorrectly rest of the things all are perfect

I need to do something like if the page index is the last index then i have change the buttons label.

```
- (PageContentViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    if (([self.pageImages count] == 0) || (index >= [self.pageImages count])) {
        return nil;
    }

    // Create a new view controller and pass suitable data.
    PageContentViewController *pageContentViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PageContentViewController"];
    pageContentViewController.imageFile = self.pageImages[index];
    pageContentViewController.titleText = self.pageTitles[index];

    pageContentViewController.pageIndex = index;

    NSLog(@"INDEX : %lu", (unsigned long)index);

    return pageContentViewController;
}

- (void)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewCntr didFinishAnimating:(BOOL)finished previousViewControllers:(NSArray *)previousViewControllers transitionCompleted:(BOOL)completed
{
    NSInteger currentIndex = ((UIViewController *)self.pageViewController.viewControllers.firstObject).view.tag;
    if (completed) pageControl.currentPage = currentIndex;
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSInteger index = ((PageContentViewController *)viewController).pageIndex;

    if (index == NSNotFound || !index) return nil;
    NSLog(@"INDEX : %lu", (unsigned long)index);
    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index-1];
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSInteger index = ((PageContentViewController *)viewController).pageIndex;

    if (index == NSNotFound || index == pageCount-1) return nil;
    NSLog(@"INDEX : %lu", (unsigned long)index);
    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index+1];
}



- (NSInteger)presentationCountForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController{

    return [self.pageImages count];

}

- (NSInteger)presentationIndexForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController{

    return 0;
}
```

I tried many way but couldn't resolve the problem.

Help me in finding the current index of the page.
Index of the page is not showing currently when i swipe one time it returns me 0,1 index at a time and for next swipe it shows me 2 and for next swipe it does not return me any index

Comment: what pageContentViewController.pageIndex printing when it is last page? how many pages do you have?

Comment: @SanketBhavsar It shows different index from left to right and right to left it is incorrect index

Comment: How are you calling the method shown?  What does it return/do?  What do you expect it to return/do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have implemented the same code and after debugging, got to know that the  `PageViewControllerDataSource` methods are getting called twice. So you can use `willTransitionToViewControllers` method instead of `viewControllerBeforeViewController` and `viewControllerAfterViewController` methods to get the proper index.

Please refer following answer,

[PageViewController delegate functions called twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17608179/pageviewcontroller-delegate-functions-called-twice)

Comment: can you provide me some more explanation

Comment: `willTransitionToViewControllers` will still get called if the transition doesn't complete, so shouldn't be used to keep track of the index.